# PHP: How to integrate userid in paypal IPN system?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

When users are logged in, the userid is stored in User::Data('id').

How can i use the userid in the html-form and how to access the variable in the IPN listener so I update the correct account when the payment is sucessfull?

This is my current button-code.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="..">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Amount">Amount</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="100">100$100,00 USD</option>
    <option value="150">150$140,00 USD</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/no_NO/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

This is the listener im currently using: https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN/tree/58e029c235133b041006a45a9ce614739d8eb550

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using "hidden" form-element in HTML?
Like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="medusa1414" />
```

You can add it using PHP with the userid, User::Data('id')? as you said.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="..">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Amount">Amount</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="100">100$100,00 USD</option>
    <option value="150">150$140,00 USD</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<?php echo '<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="' . $user_id . '" />'; ?>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/no_NO/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

You will be able to receive this value at PHP by using

```
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
```

Comment: The `custom` field can also be used, alternatively.

Comment: Is there a method to make this field required? In opera you can edit out the hidden field and submit the form. Then the user wil get charged and dont receview anything.

Comment: You can edit it almost at all browsers, thats the HTML. If the user want his money to be wasted, let him. Why a user should change the HTML code anyway? User should do the stuff via graphical interface.